# debug is not working

Tags: java, debugging

I am working on struts2 framework, when I am debuging a webapp it starting debuging but directly showing below page..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG26V.png)

my struts.xml code is there for this method

```
        <action name="submitRegistration" class="Actions.LoginActionn" method="submitRegistration" >
           <result name="success">reg.jsp</result> 
        </action>
```

and the Action method is...

```
 public String submitRegistration(){

            Session hibernatesession=null; 
            try{
                hibernatesession=hibernateAllahrakha.getSession();
                hibernat

esession.beginTransaction();
            Daofactory dfact= new  Daofactory();
            LoginDao ld= dfact.LoginConfigureManager();

        boolean save=ld.saveuser(hibernatesession, ust);
        if(save){

            System.out.println("yes");
        }
        else{

            System.out.println("no");
        }

            hibernatesession.getTransaction().commit();

        }
        catch(Exception e){

            System.out.println("Exception occour in Submit Regestration "+e);
        }
        finally {
            if(hibernatesession!=null){
                hibernatesession.flush();
                hibernatesession.close();
            }
        }

        return SUCCESS; 
    }
```

How can I debug properly? I put debugging point in the line where 
`Session hibernatesession=null;` 
and
`boolean save=ld.saveuser(hibernatesession, ust);`

Comment: _Source not found_ means that you do not have access to the source code of the API you are using. If the code is open source, you can download it and link it, so you can look at what happens inside the API. If not, there's nothing much you can do. It's one of the inherent problems of using a framework.

Comment: In the attached image, the error is related to LoginActionn.submitRegistration(). Is that a simple typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that the debugger can not find your project souce. To do that open "source lookup path" and select and link your project source folder to source to resolve the issue.

Comment: How can i Do this?

Comment: Right click on your project and click on Properties and in the properties dialog click on Java Build Path. In the Source tab you should see the folder of your source code. If not you need to add it.